# Using <embed> in Javadoc with -Xdoclint

Tags: svg, embed, javadoc, java-8

We use `<embed>` in the javadoc for the following page, which allows the hyperlinks in the SVG images to properly link between pages of our documentation.
http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNState.html

The new `-Xdoclint` feature in JDK 8 produces the following build error for each instance of this:

> org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNState.java:[67,4] unknown tag: embed

How can we retain this HTML tag in our documentation, but still allow the project to build with the additional information provided by `-Xdoclint` feature?

Comment: You may find something in the [javadoc mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/javadoc-dev/)

Comment: Jan, not a solution but you may find more info in this piece by Stephen Colebourne: http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html. At least it gives some historical background re this decision from the Java core team.